# Explicitly Mapping of observations from a general set S into an inner product space

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am learning **"Kenel Tricks"** for SVM. When I was searching I had to read the passage from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick) as follows:

```
 "For machine learning algorithms, the kernel trick is a way of mapping observations 
from a general set S into an inner product space V (equipped with its natural norm), 
without ever having to compute the mapping explicitly, in the hope that the 
observations will gain meaningful linear structure in V"
```

My Question from above passage is:

1. What is meant by **"compute the mapping explicitly"**?

Can any one please define it with some real time example or give me some referential web sites. So it will help in understanding kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there in the same article:

> The trick to avoid the explicit mapping is to use learning algorithms
>   that only require dot products between the vectors in V, and choose
>   the mapping such that these high-dimensional dot products can be
>   computed within the original space, by means of a kernel function.

That means that one can avoid computing the images of the data points in the [multidimensional] kernel space and instead only calculate the pairwise dot product of these images, which often turns out to be cheaper. There's an example [here](http://www.cogsys.wiai.uni-bamberg.de/teaching/ss06/hs_svm/slides/SVM_and_Kernels.pdf), as well as in pretty nearly **every** book on SVM's.